# Access to variables through delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've go a situatiion in Objective-C where I'm trying to access an object's variable through another object. The classes (simplified):

## A.h

```
@interface A : NSObject {  
  NSMutableArray *someStuff;  
}  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *someStuff;    

@end
```

## A.m

```
@implementation A  

@synthesize someStuff;  

//  blah, blah, blah
```

Then, because I'm doing an iPhone app, there is an app delegate that contains a variable of this object type:

## AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {  

   A *aPtr;  
}  

@property (nonatomic, retain) A *aPtr;  
@end
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate  

@synthesize aPtr;  
// blah, blah, blah
```

Then, in another class (in this a view controller), I'm trying to access 'someStuff' in this manner:

## AViewController.m

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  

NSMutableArray *someArray = appDelegate.aPtr.someStuff;
```

So, the problem is that this blows up in fine fashion. I think I'm too much of a Java junkie to understand why this won't work. Can anyone elighten me?

Many thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize this in this way

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  

NSMutableArray *someArray = appDelegate.someArray;
```

This will resolve your problem.....

Comment: wrong, casting is unnecessary, the code above shouldn't break (and doesn't break - just checked it)

Comment: Ok, I tried that. The compiler complains that someStuff is not a an object in AppDelegate (which it isn't of course). The compiler error I get normally is that someStuff is not an object of A.  Still stuck.

Comment: So you have a compiler error and not runtime error? You should have stated it. Check that you have all the includes in place, so that the compiler knows which attriutes belong to which class and that you don't have more than one version of the A class that you might have included, one without someStuff.

Comment: I think you must be importing your delegate in the .m class and not declaring the class of your delegate in .h class.Declare  your delegate in .h as @Class yourdelegate and  import it in .m class.

Answer (score 0):

Craig,

`appDelegate.aPtr` will return `null`. as it is not initialized yet, and when you try to access some member of a `null` object,(in java `NULLPointerException`).Its behavior is as expected.(this blows up in fine fashion).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ravin is correct. The class definition defines the iVars and properties for a class so you have defined an iVar `aPtr` that references an object of type `A`. However, you have not allocated and initialized this object.

An example using the default initialization would be `aPtr = [[A alloc] init]'.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I did initialize aPtr. Your response is correct considering I didn't mention that. But it is initialized so there's something more that I'm missing.

Comment: That's fine but the answer you accepted doesn't really address your problem. 1) Casting is not required, 2) You didn't declare the iVar/property `someArray`, and 3) he didn't go to the next level of indirection that you did in the code you posted to get to `aPtr.someStuff`. As long as you're happy, glad things are working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds suspicious since in ObjC you are allowed to send messages to nil without a problem and properties are just diguised methods. For example you can

```
view = nil;
view.hidden = NO;
```

and it doesn't blow up, it just does nothing.

So since appDelegate.aPtr.someStuff is just

```
[[appDelegate aPtr] someStuff];
```

and [appDelegate aPtr] does nothing and returns nil so it should be safe to call [[appDelegate aPtr] someStuff] without a problem but also without any results.

So while it is a problem with using objects that hadn't been initialized (which most often should be done in a designated constructor of the appropriate object), since you don't get results that you expect, in my undestanding of "sending message to nil" in ObjC it shouldn't blow up. If it is then either I am missing the point or something other causes the problem and not this call.

**EDIT**

just checked: if not initialized at all it works as I explained: ObjC allows messages to be sent to nil:

```
A *aPtr = appDelegate.aPtr;
NSMutableArray *someArray = aPtr.someStuff;
NSLog(@"%@", someArray);
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = appDelegate.aPtr.someStuff;
NSLog(@"%@", someArray);
```

both don't break and print null.

If you initialize A properly but not initialize someStuff in A it still doesn't break but print null. The problem might be that you initialize aPtr to a different class than A, in which case you get unrecognized selector exception (you should be able to see it in the error log) and program crash.